# How to add the Time Capsule to an existing network, in Ethernet?

Tags: network, wifi, airport, time-capsule, ethernet

I have just received my new Time Capsule.

I don’t want to create a new AirPort network, I already have one.

I want to connect the Time Capsule to my existing network, in Ethernet. I plan to plug the Time Capsule to my wi-fi access point & router (Freebox), with a (gigabit) Ethernet cable.

- Which Ethernet port of the Time Capsule do I use ? LAN or WAN ? I prefer to use the LAN port, I don’t want my Time Capsule to have anything to do with my Internet connection.
- How do I configure the Time Capsule ?

The guy from Apple’s tech support happened to be a joke.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late, but I just solved this issue on my own home network.

I added the Time Capsule as a normal client on the LAN. Plug it into the LAN port, and it'll be fine. Then you just have to turn off the network creation settings — and you're golden!

Wish I'd found this sooner.